# Problems trying to mock a Model within Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: testing, flask, mocking, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm testing a Flask application that have some SQLAlchemy models using Flask-SQLAlchemy and I'm having some problems trying to mock a few models to some methods that receive some models as parameters.

A toy version of what I'm trying to do is like this. Suppose I have a model given by:

```
// file: database.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()  

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    birthday = db.Column(db.Date)
```

That is imported in an app that is built with the app factory pattern:

```
// file: app.py
from flask import Flask
from database import db

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
    db.init_app(app)
```

And some function that needs a `User` as parameter:

```
// file: actions.py
import datetime

SECONDS_IN_A_YEAR = 31556926

def get_user_age(user):
    return (datetime.date.today() - user.birthday).total_seconds() //  SECONDS_IN_A_YEAR
```

Moreover there should be a couple of views and blueprints that are imported in `app.py` and registered in the app that latter call the function `get_user_age` somewhere.

My problem is: I want to test the function `get_user_age` without having to create an app, registering with a fake database, etc, etc. That shouldn't be necessary, the function is totally independent from the fact that it is used in a Flask app.

So I tried:

```
import unittest

import datetime
import mock

from database import User
from actions import get_user_age

class TestModels(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_user_age(self):
        user = mock.create_autospec(User, instance=True)
        user.birthday = datetime.date(year=1987, month=12, day=1)
        print get_user_age(user)
```

That raises me a `RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context` exception. So I thought "yeah, obviously I must patch some object to prevent it from checking if the app is registered with the database and etc". So I tried decorating it with `@mock.patch("database.SQLAlchemy")` and other things to no avail.

Do anyone know what should I patch to prevent this behavior, or even if my test strategy is all wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found another way around this problem. The basic idea is to control the access to static attributes. I used pytest and mocker, but the code could be adapted to use unittest.

Let's look at a working code example and than explain it:

```
import pytest

import datetime

import database

from actions import get_user_age


@pytest.fixture
def mock_user_class(mocker):
    class MockedUserMeta(type):
        static_instance = mocker.MagicMock(spec=database.User)

        def __getattr__(cls, key):
            return MockedUserMeta.static_instance.__getattr__(key)

    class MockedUser(metaclass=MockedUserMeta):
        original_cls = database.User
        instances = []

        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            MockedUser.instances.append(
                mocker.MagicMock(spec=MockedUser.original_cls))
            MockedUser.instances[-1].__class__ = MockedUser
            return MockedUser.instances[-1]

    mocker.patch('database.User', new=MockedUser)


class TestModels:
    def test_test_get_user_age(self, mock_user_class):
        user = database.User()
        user.birthday = datetime.date(year=1987, month=12, day=1)
        print(get_user_age(user))
```

The test is pretty clear and to the point. The fixture does all the heavy lifting:

- `MockedUser` would replace the original `User` class - it would create a new mock object with the right spec every time it's needed
- The purpose of `MockedUserMeta` has to be explained a bit further: SQLAlchemy has a nasty syntax which involves static functions. Imagine your tested code has a line similar to this `from_db = User.query.filter(User.id == 20).one()`, you should have a way to mock the response: `MockedUserMeta.static_instance.query.filter.return_value.one.return_value.username = 'mocked_username'`

This is the best method that I found which allows to have tests without any db access and without any flask app, while allowing to mock SQLAlchemy query results.

Since I don't like writing this boilerplate over and over, [I have created a helper library](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) to do it for me. Here is the code I wrote to generate the needed stuff for your example:

```
from mock_autogen.pytest_mocker import PytestMocker
print(PytestMocker(database).mock_classes().mock_classes_static().generate())
```

The output is:

```
class MockedUserMeta(type):
    static_instance = mocker.MagicMock(spec=database.User)

    def __getattr__(cls, key):
        return MockedUserMeta.static_instance.__getattr__(key)

class MockedUser(metaclass=MockedUserMeta):
    original_cls = database.User
    instances = []

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        MockedUser.instances.append(mocker.MagicMock(spec=MockedUser.original_cls))
        MockedUser.instances[-1].__class__ = MockedUser
        return MockedUser.instances[-1]

mocker.patch('database.User', new=MockedUser)
```

Which is exactly what I needed to place in my fixture.

Comment: I marking this as a better answer than my own, because it's more modern and elegant and it deserves some love. Very nice!

Comment: Thanks @RafaelS.Calsaverini, love the feedback and appreciation

Answer (score 11):

So, I found a solution after banging my head on the keyboard for a few hours. The problem seems to be the following (if anyone knows better, please correct me).

When I run `mock.create_autospec(User)`, the mock module tries to inspect all attributes of `User` to create the adequate spec for the Mock object it will spit out. When this happens, it tries to inspect the attribute `User.query`, which can only be evaluated when you are inside the scope of a Flask app.

This happens because when `User.query` is evaluated, an object is created that needs a valid session. This session is created by the `create_scope_session` method on the `SQLAlchemy` class inside Flask-SQLAlchemy.

This method instantiates a class called `SignallingSession` whose `__init__` method calls the `SQLAlchemy.get_app` method. This is the method that raises the `RuntimeError` when there's no app registered in the db.

By patching the SignallingSession method everything works nicely. Since I don't want to interact with the database this is ok:

```
import unittest
import datetime

import mock

from actions import age


@mock.patch("flask_sqlalchemy.SignallingSession", autospec=True)
class TestModels(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_age(self, session):
        import database

        user = mock.create_autospec(database.User)
        user.birthday = datetime.date(year=1987, month=12, day=1)
        print age(user)
```