# How to mock <ModelClass>.query.filter_by() in Flask-SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, mocking, python-unittest

### In brief

When testing a model class in Flask-SqlAlchemy, how can we mock the method `.query.filter_by()` so as to return the list of mocked model objects?

### Full details

Let's say we have a model class as below code

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    # more column mapping and methods go here
```

Then in our Flask code we call

```
SomeModel.query.filter_by(...)
```

In our testing code, using [Python unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) model with [mocking](https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python), we want to mock the `filter_by()` call so that it returns a list of model objects under our designed test case.

How can we get to that?

p.s.

My google search only found [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28194452/248616); though applying `@patch("flask_sqlalchemy.SignallingSession", autospec=True)` at the beginning of the class not work for me.

I also tried to mock the function as below code snippet

```
@patch('app.model.some_model.SomeModel.query.filter_by')
def test_some_case(self, filterbyMOCK):
    # more test logic goes here
```

and the code get immediate error when started

```
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

The full error from PyCharm IDE as snapshot below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1297, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1353, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1523, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1210, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1197, in _dot_lookup
    return getattr(thing, comp)
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 428, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 990, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.app = db.get_app()
  File "/home/namgivu/NN/code/someproject-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 809, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError('application not registered on db '
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll have to mock the whole mapper class; accessing the `query` attribute on the mapper causes a session load:

```
@patch('app.model.some_model.SomeModel')
def test_some_case(self, some_model_mock):
    filter_by_mock = some_model_mock.query.filter_by
    # more test logic goes here
```

That's because the `.query` attribute is a descriptor object; accessing it triggers the binding to a session.

The alternative would be to mock out the [`_QueryProperty.__get__` method](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/f4662ad464a73befa47cf74754fdbfe156570e59/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L494-L500) (which backs the `.query` attribute); only use this if you *must* test with actual `SomeModel` instances:

```
@patch('flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty.__get__')
def test_some_case(self, query_property_getter_mock):
    filter_by_mock = query_property_getter_mock.return_value.filter_by
    # more test logic goes here
```

Demo:

```
>>> from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
>>> db = SQLAlchemy()
>>> class SomeModel(db.Model):
...     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
...
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> with mock.patch('__main__.SomeModel') as model_mock:
...     filter_by = model_mock.query.filter_by
...     SomeModel.query.filter_by(SomeModel.id == 'foo')
...
<MagicMock name='SomeModel.query.filter_by()' id='4438980312'>
>>> with mock.patch('flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty.__get__') as query_property_getter_mock:
...     filter_by_mock = query_property_getter_mock.return_value.filter_by
...     SomeModel.query.filter_by(SomeModel.id == 'foo')
...
<MagicMock name='__get__().filter_by()' id='4439035184'>
```

Comment: @NamGVU: the rest of your model will also depend on SQLAlchemy properties and is not part of the system under test. When you are testing if code using queries is working, you are not testing if the model is working (which is mostly SQLAlchemy's domain to test, not yours). It is better to just mock the whole model in that case.

Comment: One more thing comes up today @Martijn Pieters, when do we go to  inner attribute via `return_value` and when NOT to?

Comment: @NamGVU: you can use a `()` call too, but you can't use that as an assignment target. So `filter_by_mock = query_property_getter_mock().filter_by` works, but `filter_by_mock() = faked_result_set` doesn't. So I personally prefer to use `.return_value` everywhere to keep code symmetrical and to aid readability to newcomers to my code and the Python mocking library.

Answer (score 8):

Just a sum-up from [Martijn Pieters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482171/248616)

Target

- We want to mock `.query.filter_by().all()` result
  e.g. `SomeModel.query.filter_by().all()`

Code 01

```
@patch('flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty.__get__')
def test (
  self,
  queryMOCK,
):

  #setup
  queryMOCK\
    .return_value.filter_by\
    .return_value.all\
    .return_value = [1,22]

  #get actual
  modelObj = SomeModel.query.filter_by().all()
  print(modelObj)
```

Code 02 - similar as above and using `with`

```
def test(self):
  with patch('flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty.__get__') as queryMOCK      #setup
    queryMOCK\
      .return_value.filter_by\
      .return_value.all\
      .return_value = [1,22]

    #get actual
    modelObj = SomeModel.query.filter_by().all()
    print(modelObj)
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to mock both filter_by and delete?

Comment: Not sure. Please refer to original author Pieters https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482171/248616