# How to mock <ModelClass>.query.filter in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I am not able to unit test a particular block of code in my project.
Here is the snippet of code:

```
@process_bp.route("/getListCSV")
def get_list_csv():
    industry_sele = "All"
    #rest of code
    if industry_sele != "All":
        companies_flask_list = Companies.query.filter(Companies.industry_desc == industry_sele)
```

I have tried all the ways of writing a unit testcase for this from here-> [How to mock <ModelClass>.query.filter_by() in Flask-SqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482021/how-to-mock-modelclass-query-filter-by-in-flask-sqlalchemy)
The test case passed but the testcase didn't cover the snippet of code. What could be the reason for that? How to do it in a proper way? please help