# How to mock multiple query.filter_by in Flaks-SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy

### In brief

When testing in Flask-SqlAlchemy how can I mock multiple differents query.filter_by().first ?

### More in detail

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482021/how-to-mock-modelclass-query-filter-by-in-flask-sqlalchemy) to do some unit testing and it works very well when I have only one query.filter_by.

The problem is in one function I have:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(username=user["username"]).first()
organization = Organization.query.filter_by(organization_name=user.get("organization")).first()
```

If I follow the previous link when I do:

```
@mock.patch('flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty.__get__')
def test(self, queryMOCK):
    queryMOCK \
        .return_value.filter_by \
        .return_value.first \
        .return_value = user
```

I mock all the query.filter_by() and not only one of the two.

They say to do:

```
@patch('app.model.some_model.SomeModel')
def test_some_case(self, some_model_mock):
    filter_by_mock = some_model_mock.query.filter_by
```

but I didn't manage to do it.

Comment: You want to test the filter condition or the query as a whole?

Comment: None, I have a function that use both of the queries, I want to mock both the queries independently.

Comment: Did you find a solution @GustaveJULIEN? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify if all filters are there you can do that by making your code testable

```py
def get_filters():
    return [Organization.organization_name == 'xyz', Organization.property2 == 'abc', ]
```

and then verify the output of get_filters()

in the actual query, you can then pass the output of filter such as

```py
filters = get_filters()
session.query.filter(*filters)
```

I would suggest not get into mocking ORM methods because that will complicate them. instead, make the code testable.

Answer (score 0):

on the last line

```
.return_value = user
```

change to

```
.side_effect = [user, organization]
```

side_effect is basically just return_value but takes an iterator instead of one value.